Angular 17 deferable views on trigger with different when viewport
Does anybody knows will it be possible to pass different container when view port in triggers ?
for example:
<div #container>
  @defer(on container) {
   <item />
 }@placeholder {
   <div>Placeholder</div>
}
</div>

or something similar to this?

Yes, this use case is mentionned in the docs. You have to use the on viewport trigger.
<div #container>
  @defer(on viewport(container)) {
   <item />
 }@placeholder {
   <div>Placeholder</div>
}
</div>


This use case not quiet what i'm looking for. i wont the defer components would be loaded when intersecting with the container element and not a viewport. in the case you've mentioned the defered element would be loaded when greetings ref element intersects with the viewport.

it's works the same with your example

@AlexAlex I believe that this answer does exactly what you ask in your question. If not I suggest you improve your question, since it is not clear what you otherwise are after...
